# How to set up VPN connection for Windows 8 migrating from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, windows-8.1

I can succeed to set up VPN connection to my company in Windows 7. But in Windows 8, with the box asking to choose VPN type, I have no idea what to choose.

Please help if you know how to.

In Windows 7 I connect using `Point to Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP)` though, can't find the similar type in Windows 8.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [guide](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/index.php?p=/discussion/315/windows-8-how-to-configure-pptp-with-windows-built-in-client-on-windows-8/p1) for setting it up with a commercial VPN provider.  You can substitute your workplace specific info where needed.

Comment: The steps 01 to 04 in the guide is correct but from steps 05, I can't find it on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Hit `Start` and type "sharing" to open `Network and Sharing Center`.

Go for `Create new network`

[image]

Then choose `VPN connection` type and type in your VPN server's URL to connect to; finally just name your connection.

Then connect to this newly created connection; you may be asked to enter username and password.

[image]

I then just enter mine and it just works without knowing the VPN type as [mentioned in the OP](https://superuser.com/q/771070/34893) to set up VPN.

What a Windows 8.1 !